# Call C++ Hello World from Julia

Tags: c++, julia

I have a C++ program that parses a binary file and outputs a std::string.  I would like to call this function directly from Julia and convert the steam into a DataFrame.  I need it to work in Linux and Windows.  Currently, I have the program write the output to a text file, and then I read it into Julia.  Cxx is no longer supported, and trying to get CxxWrap to work has been an exercise in frustration.

Toy Problem:
If someone could show me how to call the code below from Julia, that would be awesome.

```
// the example from https://github.com/JuliaInterop/CxxWrap.jl
#include <string>
std::string greet()
{
 return "hello, world";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new package which might fit your needs here:

https://github.com/eschnett/CxxInterface.jl

It is intended as a successor to `Cxx.jl` and more stable, so I'd recommend giving it ago although I haven't tried it myself!

Comment: Thank you.  I will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old thread, I had just carried out this exercise myself yesterday, so I'm sharing my solution here. This was tested on Julia/1.8.4, cmake/3.11.1, and gcc/12.1.0 on a linux system.

#### Step 0

I used [CxxWrap.jl](https://github.com/JuliaInterop/CxxWrap.jl). First I had to make a `libcxxwrap_julia_jll` JLL library, following [its github instructions](https://github.com/JuliaInterop/libcxxwrap-julia). Once it's done, I got a new folder `~/.julia/dev/libcxxwrap_julia_jll/override`

#### Step 1

Create a `hello.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include "jlcxx/jlcxx.hpp"

std::string greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

JLCXX_MODULE define_julia_module(jlcxx::Module& mod)
{
  mod.method("greet", &greet);
}
```

and the `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
project(HelloWorld)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")

find_package(JlCxx)
get_target_property(JlCxx_location JlCxx::cxxwrap_julia LOCATION)
get_filename_component(JlCxx_location ${JlCxx_location} DIRECTORY)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib;${JlCxx_location}")

message(STATUS "Found JlCxx at ${JlCxx_location}")

add_library(hello SHARED hello.cpp)

target_link_libraries(hello JlCxx::cxxwrap_julia)

install(TARGETS
  hello
LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
RUNTIME DESTINATION lib)
```

They exist in the same directory.

#### Step 2

Build the shared library (`.io`) file via

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=your_path_to/libcxxwrap_julia_jll/override your_path_to_src
cmake --build . --config Release
```

where `your_path_to_src` is the directory that contains `hello.cpp` and `CMakeList.txt`.

#### step 3

Call hello world in Julia:

```
# Load the module and generate the functions
module CppHello
using CxxWrap
@wrapmodule("your_path_to/build/lib/libhello")

function __init__()
    @initcxx
end
end

# Call greet and show the result
CppHello.greet() # prints "hello, world"
```

Obviously, all of this info is present in the README file of [CxxWrap.jl](https://github.com/JuliaInterop/CxxWrap.jl). I just laid it out here in a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  It seems that none of the old solutions worked.  I eventually rewrote my code in pure C, which worked very well.  When I get time, I will check this out.  It looks very promising.